# firebase-admin node.js sdk: getUser() and listUsers() return different values in customClaims

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Im setting custom-claims on users with `setUserCustomClaims`.
We have an endpoint to get info of current logged in user where we use the function

```
firebase
        .auth()
        .getUser(user.firebaseId)
```

In the response we can access `customClaims.userType` which is a property we set.

But when we use

```
firebase
   .auth()
   .listUsers()
```

for the same user, `customClaims.userType` is just an empty string

Any idea here?

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the SDK, you should file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/) using the code you use that illustrates and reproduces the issue so that anyone can verify if it's working as expected.